# Dispatched action received by reducer, but not appearing in action list and not rerendering

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a Comment component that has a delete button.  When the button is clicked, it called the action, makes the axios call, and when the call returns it dispatches the update to the reducer.  The only problem is that it's not triggering the rerender of the parent component.  The action, although it is updating the state, does not appear in the list of dispatched actions in the Redux DevTools.  All other actions work and display in the DevTools, but for some reason this one doesn't.

My thought after reading the comment section below is that it's because I'm making a shallow copy of my object.  Am I wrong to think that making a shallow copy, modifying a deeper object, and returning the shallow copy wouldn't trigger a rerender?  Isn't the fact that the shallow object is a different reference enough to trigger it?  I'm confident I'm doing this the same way in other places and I havenn't have a problem elsewhere.  It

This is the action list in Redux DevTools after deleting the comment.  I would expect that it would have "delete_comment" near the bottom somewhere, but it's not:
[image]

The data is passed from the parent components CommentList -> CommentThread -> Comment.

Is this truly dispatching?

This is a simplified component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {
    deleteComment,
} from "../../actions/comment_actions";


class Comment extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    }

    render() {
        const {comment, data} = this.props;

        if (!data) {
            //console.log("mir_data doesnt exist");
            return <div/>;
        }


        return (
            <div key={"comment" + comment.id} id={"c" + comment.id}>
            <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteComment(comment.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        user: state.user
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        deleteComment,
    }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Comment);
```

Here's a simplified action file:

```
export const DELETE_COMMENT = 'delete_comment';

export function deleteComment(id, callback = null) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        axiosInstance.post('/delete-comment/', {comment_id: id}, getState().api.axios).then(
            response => {
                dispatch(dispatchDeleteComment(id));

                //dispatch(dispatchViewUserInfo(response.data));
                if (response.status === 200)
                    callback();
            }
        );
    }
}


export function dispatchDeleteComment(id) {
    return {
        type: DELETE_COMMENT,
        payload: id
    };
}
```

Here's the simplified reducer:

```
import {DELETE_COMMENT} from "../actions/comment_actions";

export default function(state = {}, action){
    let newState = {...state};
    switch(action.type){

        case DELETE_COMMENT:
            //some logic
            delete newState.comments[action.payload];
            return newState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure about the "not showing up in the DevTools" part.  However, looking at your code, I do see two (probably unrelated) issues.  First, you _are_ mutating your state with that `delete newState.comments[action.payload]` line, because you're only making a shallow copy. See the [Redux docs page on "Immutable Update Patterns"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) for an explanation. Second, you can simplify to `const mapDispatch = {deleteComment}`.  What does your store setup code look like?

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to do with the store, as all of my other actions function as expected.